# Getting all occurrences of elements on a specific positions, and show them as ToolTip in JavaFX

Tags: java, list, javafx

I want to get all occurrences of elements in specific indexes from a list, and append them all together, then add them to list. Later in UpdatItem method of a TreeTableView I will use this String as tooltip.

I have a List Like:

`ListValue = [AUF_1426597200377_183, Function 19, Paper-based appl. component 3, hasType, yellow, Paper-based appl. component 2,  hasType, yellow, Computer-based appl. component 3, hasType, Green],`

I need to get all elements which are coming just before element `hasType` and append them to StringBuilder:

Which means I need to have these 3 Strings, and append them in StringBuilder:

```
Paper-based appl. component 3,Paper-based appl. component 2,Computer-based appl. component 3
```

Then I want to use them as mouse tooltip, and show them vertically like:

```
Paper-based appl. component 3
Paper-based appl. component 2
Computer-based appl. component 3
```

I have tried this, but it gives me only the first occurrence of the element.

```
StringBuilder tooltip = new StringBuilder();
for(int k = 0;k<listValue.size();k++){
tooltip.append(listValue.get(list.indexOf("hasType")-1));
            }
  result.add(2, tooltip.toString());
```

Then in my UpdateItem method I can see only a long String of first element comming before first hasType. item.get(2) has the second value of result

```
setTooltip(new Tooltip(item.get(2)));
```

Comment: i do not need that, only all elements which are coming before hasType

Comment: I mean the element which is at the cell before hasType

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
    StringBuilder tooltip = new StringBuilder();

    for(int k = 0;k<list.size();k++){
        if(list.get(k).equals("hasType"))
            tooltip.append(Collections.singleton(list.get(k-1))+"\n");
                }

        result.add(2, tooltip.toString());
```

I use this in tooltip in updateItem and works perfectly